# C and Python code to Java help

Tags: java, python, c, endianness

I'm trying to read in some bytes from a file in Java and then create bitmasks from some of the data and lengths and offsets from others.

I'm so close to getting my program working but I keep getting garbled data coming out the other end.

I'm 90% sure my problem is something to do with the way that Java is reading the bytes in.

There is some Python and C code that I'm basing my design on but I don't know how to convert this into Java.  I've tried wrapping a byte[] in a byteBuffer but I'm still getting confusing results.

This is what I'm trying to get my head around:

bitmask:= copy inputBuffer[inputIndex] as 32-bit integer in little-endian format - needs to be four bytes

In C this is done as:

```
bitmask= (inputBuffer[inputIndex + 3] << 24) | (inputBuffer[inputIndex + 2] << 16) |
                        (inputBuffer[inputIndex + 1] <<  8) | inputBuffer[inputIndex];
```

In Python this is: `bitmask= unpack("<L", inputBuffer[inputIndex:inputIndex + 4])[0]`

Until I can get this working correctly my program is falling over.

Can anyone offer any information on the best way of implementing this?

Many thanks

Tony

Comment: Please post the Java code you're trying to use.

Comment: I've put a bit of the code here http://www.mrthaggar.com/partialCode.txt


Apologies for it being a bit messy, I hope you can understand what I'm trying to do from it!!

Comment: @user583240: Please add the Java code you're trying to use **to this question**.  Please add the exact part that's supposed to match the Python and C parts.  Please **update** the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set ByteBuffer's byteOrder to littleEndian and just use getInt